# I need to set a Status Column to "created" once the script has run

Tags: google-apps-script

I have code that splits the rows in google sheets, and puts that info into google doc and then converts to pdf. It moves that pdf to a destination folder. All i need now is when that is done how do i get the script to update my status column (column AH) to "Created" so it doesn't send duplicates. 
(sorry im very new to apps script)

Code is as follows:

```
PDF Creator - Email all responses
=================================
```

When you click "Create PDF > Create a PDF for each row" this script 
constructs a PDF for each row in the attached GSheet. The value in the 
"File Name" column is used to name the file and - if there is a 
value - it is emailed to the recipient in the "Email" column.

```
  // Config
  // ------


  //  1. Create a GDoc template and put the ID here

  var TEMPLATE_ID = '1R5Z_7........'

  // 2. You can specify a name for the new PDF file here, or leave empty to use the 
// name of the template or specify the file name in the sheet

var PDF_FILE_NAME = ''
// 3. If an email address is specified you can email the PDF

var EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'The email subject ---- UPDATE ME -----'
var EMAIL_BODY = 'The email body ------ UPDATE ME ---------'

// 4. If a folder ID is specified here this is where the PDFs will be located

var RESULTS_FOLDER_ID = '1DHiPL......'

// Constants
// ---------

// You can pull out specific columns values 
var FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME = 'File Name'
var EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME = 'Email Address'
var NAME_COLUMN_NAME = 'First Name'
var JOB_COLUMN_NAME = 'Job Description'




// The format used for any dates 
var DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy/MM/dd';

/**
 * Eventhandler for spreadsheet opening - add a menu.
 */

function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu('[ Create PDFs ]')
    .addItem('Create a PDF for each row', 'createPdfs')
    .addToUi()

} // onOpen()

/**  
 * Take the fields from each row in the active sheet
 * and, using a Google Doc template, create a PDF doc with these
 * fields replacing the keys in the template. The keys are identified
 * by having a % either side, e.g. %Name%.
 */

function createPdfs() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

  if (TEMPLATE_ID === '') {    
    ui.alert('TEMPLATE_ID needs to be defined in code.gs')
    return
  }

  // Set up the docs and the spreadsheet access

  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID)
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var allRows = activeSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var headerRow = allRows.shift()

  // Create a PDF for each row

  allRows.forEach(function(row) {

    createPdf(templateFile, headerRow, row)

    // Private Function
    // ----------------

    /**
     * Create a PDF
     *
     * @param {File} templateFile
     * @param {Array} headerRow
     * @param {Array} activeRow
     */

    function createPdf(templateFile, headerRow, activeRow) {

      var headerValue
      var activeCell
      var ID = null
      var recipient = null
      var copyFile
      var numberOfColumns = headerRow.length
      var copyFile = templateFile.makeCopy()      
      var copyId = copyFile.getId()
      var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
      var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection()

      // Replace the keys with the spreadsheet values and look for a couple
      // of specific values

      for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++) {

        headerValue = headerRow[columnIndex]
        activeCell = activeRow[columnIndex]
        activeCell = formatCell(activeCell);

        copyBody.replaceText('<<' + headerValue + '>>', activeCell)

        if (headerValue === FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME) {

          ID = activeCell

        } else if (headerValue === EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME) {

          recipient = activeCell
        }
      }

      // Create the PDF file

      copyDoc.saveAndClose()
      var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'))  
      copyFile.setTrashed(true)

      // Rename the new PDF file

      if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {

        newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)

      } else if (ID !== null){

        newFile.setName(ID)
      }

      // Put the new PDF file into the results folder

      if (RESULTS_FOLDER_ID !== '') {

        DriveApp.getFolderById(RESULTS_FOLDER_ID).addFile(newFile)
        DriveApp.removeFile(newFile)
      }

      // Email the new PDF

  //    if (recipient !== null) {

  //      MailApp.sendEmail(
  //        recipient, 
  //       EMAIL_SUBJECT, 
  //        EMAIL_BODY,
  //        {attachments: [newFile]})
  //    }

    }  // createPdfs.createPdf()

  })

  ui.alert('New PDF files created')

  return

  // Private Functions
  // -----------------

  /**
  * Format the cell's value
  *
  * @param {Object} value
  *
  * @return {Object} value
  **/

  function formatCell(value) {

    var newValue = value;

    if (newValue instanceof Date) {

      newValue = Utilities.formatDate(
        value, 
        Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 
        DATE_FORMAT);

    } else if (typeof value === 'number') {

      newValue = Math.round(value * 100) / 100
    }

    return newValue;

  } // createPdf.formatCell()

    } // createPdfs()
```

Answer (score 0):

I minutely reviewed your code and as per my understanding you want to write back "Created" to cell who's row data has been used to create PDF.

What you can do, in your `forEach(function(row){})` function add one more extra parameter index (counter) which keeps the loop iteration number  then you can use this counter as your row number to refer in which cell the "Created" word go.

Example:

```
function createPdfs(){
  ........
  allRows.forEach(function(row,index) {
    ........
    //Once PDF created
    var colNum=5; //Column number where you want to write "Created" 
    updateCell(parseInt(index)+2,colNum,"Created"); 
    ........
  })
}
```

here is your updateCell function, you can write this in your same function as well,

```
function updateCell(rowNum,colNum,value){
  var ss=sheet activation code
  ss.getRange(rowNum,colNum).setValue(value);
  ........
}
```